# Self Referential Many to Many class not returning Collection in .NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm building a asp.NET Core 2.0 MVC app. I have the following self referential class:

```
public class ProductCategory
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.Html)]
            public string Description { get; set; }

            public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }

            public int MenuIconXPosition { get; set; }
            public int MenuIconYPosition { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<ProductSubCategory> ParentCategory { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<ProductSubCategory> ChildCategory { get; set; }

            public ICollection<ProductProductCategory> ProductProductCategories { get; set; }
        }
```

With the following relation class:

```
public class ProductSubCategory
    {
        public int ChildCategoryId { get; set; }
        public virtual ProductCategory ChildCategory { get; set; }

        public int ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
        public virtual ProductCategory ParentCategory { get; set; }
     }
```

In my dbContext.cs file I have the following:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<ProductSubCategory>()
        .HasKey(p => new { p.ChildCategoryId, p.ParentCategoryId });
    modelBuilder.Entity<ProductSubCategory>()
        .HasOne(p => p.ParentCategory)
        .WithMany(p => p.ChildCategory)
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.ParentCategoryId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<ProductSubCategory>()
        .HasOne(p => p.ChildCategory)
        .WithMany(p => p.ParentCategory)
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.ChildCategoryId);
```

The database migrations and updates build as expected. Populating it with data and it seems to work as expected. When iterating through the data with the following LINQ query:

```
    var result = _context.ProductCategories
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Include(i => i.ParentCategory)
        .Include(i => i.ChildCategory)
        .OrderBy(i => i.DisplayOrder);
```

The expected result would be something like `Result -> ICollection<ProductCategory> -> ICollection<ProductSubCategory> -> ICollection<ProductCategory>` but sometimes the final ICollection is null.

Sometimes the `ChildCategory` collection returns null. The `ChildCategoryId` is always assigned, so I know it is mapping correctly. The weirdest part is, what `ChildCategory` collection returns null changes depending on the `OrderBy` function. It seems to be completely arbitrary which ones in the result return null instead of the expected collection.

Any idea what I'm missing, or not understanding? I'm pretty new to asp.NET.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is just a coincidence but the only time all of the child collection entities are included correctly is when I .OrderBy( i => i.ChildCategory.Count).

If I order it in the exact opposite way, none of the child collection entities are included.

Comment: Your `ProductCategory` class has no reference to itself so there is nothing self-referential about your class.  Are you trying to achieve a tree like data structure to represent your categories?

Comment: Kind of, the product category references the subcategory, and the subcategories only properties are collections of categories.

The categories should have many parent categories and many child categories.